# Select all rows where the id is not in another table using Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, join, cakephp-2.3

Please help me to solve this in Cakephp ,
I have two tables named `employees` and `fees`.
Th `employees` table is just for employee details and the 
`fees` table is for storing added fee entries for each month for employees.

I want to get all the employees from `employees` table which were not entered for a particular month fee in `fees` table.

Simply, fetch all active employees which are not paid the fees for a selected month.

Please help me to solve this in cakephp

Table structures are listed below

Employee

```
+--------------+------------+----------+
| EmployeeId   | name       | active   |    
+--------------+------------+----------+
|      6       |    Mike    |    1     |  
|      7       |    Ethen   |    0     |
|      9       |    Sony    |    1     | 
+--------------+------------+----------+
```

Fee

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+
| FeeId  | EmployeeId  | monthYear   |    
+--------+-------------+-------------+
|   1    |     6       |  2015-09    |  
|   4    |     7       |  2015-09    |
|   6    |     6       |  2015-08    | 
+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have tried this

```
$searchFromDate = date('Y-m',strtotime($this->data['searchFromDate']));     
$this->Paginator->settings = array('fields'=>array('Employee.name'),
                'joins'=>array(
                    array(
                        'alias'=>'Fee',
                        'table'=>'fees',
                        'conditions' =>array('Fee.monthYear = '.$searchFromDate)
                    )
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'NOT' => array(
                                'Employee.EmployeeId' => 'Fee.EmployeeId'
                            )),
                'order' => array('Employee.name' => 'ASC') );
$resultData = $this->Paginator->paginate('Employee');
```

Comment: (1) You need to tag this question with the Cakephp version. (2)  Do you have a working SQL statement that you want converted to Cakephp's syntax?

Comment: Its in cakephp 2.3 and also i dont have the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change the conditions of your find to:

```
'joins'=>array(
    array(
        'alias'=>'Fee',
        'table'=>'fees',
        'conditions' =>array(
            'Fee.monthYear = $searchFromDate',
            'Employee.EmployeeId = Fee.EmployeeId'
         )
    )
),
'conditions' => array(
    'Fee.FeeId' => null
)),
```